# Uploading images in React production build does not work as intended

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm building an admin portal with React which allowed the user to add and edit images. Images I uploaded before running npm run build show up in the application just fine, however, newly uploaded images don't. I'm using multer to store images

I've tried importing from outside the src directory, but I get an error. I know i'm supposed to eject to be able to do so, but I'm kind of cautious since it's irreversible

This is part of my server's express code, part of the multer function. I have two variables, `dir` and `publicDir` I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use publicDir

```
destination: function(req, file, cb){ 

    const dir = `src/images/shops`;
    const publicDir = 'build/static/media';
    cb(null, dir)
},
```

Images get safely stored in the src folder, but it seems that the production build doesn't pick up on that

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname + '/static/media')
  }
```

The issue seems to be with the path that you have defined. its hard coded and after a build the file upload destination will still be pointing to `src/images/shops` which does not exist. You can do a small trick, you can change the destination path environment variables. (define environment production or development) and change the path.

Comment: Copying your code gave me the error "no such file or directory". How do I edit this __dirname variable?

Comment: Also, won't importing images like this cause the import error where it you're not allowed to import out of the src folder?